# using vmware 15 for running two virtual machines of 350 Gb on a laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, virtual-machine, vmware

I use vmware 15 workstation. and the virtual machines I have are 350 Gb, I have a laptop with 12 Gb of RAM and it becomes almsot unusabe for me to use my laptop. The memory which I gave to virtual machines is 2 Gb and 4 Gb so 6 Gb from my laptop is dedicated for virtualization. I use Windows 10 6 Gb remaining should be enough for my laptop to work. That is my assumption. But it becomes almsot unusable for me to use my laptop in these situations.

I can not purchase an Amazon AWS or Google cloud related thing. I don't have that much money what ever I need to do is it should be on my laptop only.So I wanted to know if there is a better solution for this kind of situation.

Comment: Do you run Windows 10 and 2 VMs off a single rotating disk or is it an SSD?

Comment: It all depends what else you're doing with your laptop, how much cpu is being used by the vms, and what's running on them. Check the performance tab of task manager on the host machine, what does cpu/ram utilization look like here? How much cpu/cores did you allocate to the vms?

Comment: I have VMware Workstation 15 here and several virtual machines: 2 or 3 GB of memory each. I can run 3 machines with no performance hit. A machine that has a 350 GB disk is very large. Are you running these on a Hard Drive?  That will likely have a big impact on performance.

Comment: There really isn’t anyway to answer this question.  I have ESXi servers that have 64 GB and Xeon processors that run dozens of 2 GB VMs are once.  What is slowing your machine down might be a half dozen different things.

Comment: Not that it helps.. but I have the same results as Ramhound and @John.  I run two or more servers with bigger loads than that and don't see a noticeable hit.  As Ramhound suggests.. it might very well be something else eating your resources.

Comment: these virtual machines are running on hard disk which is present inside laptop not on an external USB, they run on a single rotating disk.

Comment: the hard disk is 5400 rpm WDC WD10JPVX-60JC3T1 https://www.amazon.com/Western-Digital-WD10JPVX-75JC3T0-1TB-DCM/dp/B00QJIUJE4

Comment: Upgrade your system's RAM, move to an SSD for storage.  These are the most basic performance improvements.  Moving your VMs to a USB3/USB-C/thunderbolt connected NVME SSD drive would probably help with performance also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use vmware 15 workstation ...  the virtual machines I have are 350
>   Gb... it becomes almsot unusabe for me ... The hard disk is 5400 rpm
>   WDC

There is your answer right there. 5400 rpm is impossibly slow for any computer let alone a 350 GB Virtual Machine load.

You may wish to look at a much faster HOST machine; at the least, upgrade to an SSD drive as others have noted.